# What is the possible structures (closed, discrete, etc...) of the set $A$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $f$ be a non identically zero holomorphic function on the set $B=(a,b)×ℝ$. Let $g$ be a non identically zero harmonic (not holomorphic) function on the set $B=(a,b)×ℝ$. Assume that there is a set $A$ in $ℂ$ such that $f=g$. We know that the set $A$ is not open, otherwise we get $f-g$ is identically zero. My **quetion** is: What is the possible structures (closed, discrete, etc...) of the set $A$. **Any comment is helpful**.

Comment: There are no harmonic functions that are not analytic.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: You can take: $g(s)=f(s)+h(s(bar))$ where $f$ and $h$ are analytic and $s(bar)$ is the conjugate of $s$.

Comment: What you mean is that $g$ is not *holomorphic*. But it is certainly analytic (because it is harmonic).

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Yes, I have add on the question.

Comment: Analytic means: locally expressible as a power series. Harmonic means: solution of the Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$. Holomorphic means: complex differentiable in a neighbourhood. The implications go like that: holomorphic $\Rightarrow$ harmonic $\Rightarrow$ analytic and the converses do not hold.